# Set auto-fill when opening an .md file

Tags: init-file

Sadly, my Emacs is too old (and not mine to upgrade) and so I can't run markdown-mode.  I'd like to set a buffer to fill mode when I open an `.md` file.

Is there a simple way to do this?  The whole *add a hook* approach seems like overkill, but maybe it's the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `auto-mode-alist` controls setting the mode for a file based on the file extension. You can add an element for .md files with this:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
         '("\\.md\\'" . auto-fill-mode))
```

Note that `auto-fill-mode` is a minor mode, so the major mode in this case will be the default `fundamental-mode`. Depending on what you want to achieve, it might be better to set markdown files to use text mode, and add a hook for text-mode to apply auto-fill-mode in text modes.